# WebWorkers and WebSockets with Firefox

Tags: firefox, websocket, web-worker

I'm trying to implement a working WebSocket connection within a WebWorker. That should be simple and it is if I use Chrome as b rowser. However, since this experiment should further become part of a production I need it to work on all the great Browsers, namely also Firefox.

My problem is that I can't get it working with Firefox. At first Firefox wasn't able to create a WebWorker. That was a Bug and is fixed with version 9. But now it seems that it wouldn't be able to create a WebSocket within the Worker.

I tried the following line of code:

```
var ws = new WebSocket(url);
```

which fails with:

```
WebSocket is not defined
```

Well, according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) it should work. But it doesn't, neither within the WebWorker nor outside of this context. I tried the older

```
var ws = new MozWebSocket(url);
```

which seems to work outside of the WebWorker but I get the same error as above within it.

Now, what's the problem? I know WebSockets where disabled byy default in some older versions but version 9 should support a similar functionality as Chrome (at least that's what they say on their side). So am I doing something wrong?

Im using Ubuntu 11.10 and did not test other browsers yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's seems possible this is a firefox bug (not making the WebSocket object visible in WebWorkers). I would file a bug against mozilla and post back here what the response is.

Comment: This is finally fixed in [Firefox 38](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=504553#c161).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no support for WebSocket in workers in Firefox yet.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=504553

Update: Firefox 35 added support.

Comment: I see. Doesn't seem as if they are about to do something about that either. Thank you.

Comment: `Olli Pettay [:smaug] 2012-10-29 02:00:09 PDT`
_What is happening with this bug?_
           `Andrea Marchesini (:baku) 2012-10-29 04:38:29 PDT`
_I have to spend time on this bug mostly writing documentation. I think the best approach can be to review this code face to face with someone because the patch is huge, it changes too much code etc._

Comment: I just did a bump on this bugzilla ticket 504553

Comment: @ScottStensland For what it's worth, the main effect of that is to just mail a bunch of people for no good reason... it's not like the bug has been forgotten!

Comment: UPDATE: May 12, 2015 Firefox 38 allows for WebSockets in Web Workers.