# websocket in a webworkers

Tags: html, websocket

is it possible to create and use a websocket in a web worker ?

I got this error :

```
WebSocket is not defined
```

Ps : I'm using the last version of Firefox.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebWorkers and WebSockets with Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841837/webworkers-and-websockets-with-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported in Chrome (and I suspect also in IE 10 although I have tested).

There is a Firefox bug to implement the ability to use WebSockets in Web Workers: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=504553 I expect that it will be implemented in firefox within the next few months.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW FireFox 38 : I'm able to use Websockets in Webworkers.

Comment: UPDATE: May 12, 2015 Firefox 38 allows for WebSockets in Web Workers.

Answer (score 0):

A January 1, 2015 [comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=504553#c156) suggests that WebSockets created in Web Workers won't be added to FireFox until version 37. [Here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1112054) the bug is shown as fixed for version 37.